# How to reload the table when clicked reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net, fetch-api

I was wondering how will I reload only the table, not the whole page on reacts. I've tried using `history.go(0);` however, it reloads the whole page please check how can I reload it, if I was going to use `forceUpdate`, based on research you should avoid using it. I'm trying do an AJAX but I don't know what to put where to put it; it is way different than PHP.

My code for the `onclick`:

```
 handleSubmit( name, address,department){

 const laman = {
      'Employee_Name': name,
      'Address': address,
      'Department': department
    }
    return fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/PostEmployeeDetail?', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(laman)
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response)
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (result) {
      history.go(0);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);

    })
}
```

this is the code for the onclick button  plus the table itself

```
render() {
     const isEnabled = this.canBeSubmitted();
    let {jsonReturnedValue} = this.state;
  return(
    <div>
        <div className="container">   
          <h1> Listof Employees </h1>
            <button className ='btn btn-warning right ' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddEmployee"> Add an Employee</button>
             <table className= "table table-bordered" id="result"> 
                <tbody>
                 <tr>
                      <th>ID</th>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Address</th>
                      <th>Update</th>
                      <th>Delete</th>
                 </tr>
                    {jsonReturnedValue.map((d,i) => this.renderItem(d,i))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>

      {/*Updating*/}

    <div className="modal fade" id="UpdateEmployee" role="dialog">
           <div className="modal-dialog">
             <div className="modal-content">
                <div className="modal-header">
                   <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  <h4 className="modal-title">ADD  Employee</h4>
            </div>
<form>

        <div className="container">
          <div className="modal-body">
              <table> 
              <tbody>
              <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>
              <input type="text"
                    ref="Employee_Name"
                    onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, "Employee_Name")}
                    required
                    /> 
              </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td>Address</td>
              <td>
               <input type="text"
                     ref="Address"
                    onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, "Address")}
                    required
                     />
              </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td>Department</td>
              <td>
               <input type="text"
                      
                      onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, "Department")}
                      required
              /> 
              </td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
              </table>

          </div>
          </div>
          <div className="modal-footer">
            <input type="button" className="btn btn-info"disabled={!isEnabled} 
                    onClick = { this.handleSubmit.bind(
                                this, this.state.Employee_Name,
                                this.state.Address,
                                this.state.Department)
                                 }
                               value =" Add Employee"
                               data-dismiss="modal"/>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" >Close</button>
          </div>

            </form>
```

PS: IT IS ALSO IN THE SAME PAGE.. the reason I don't know how will I call it.

Comment: add your reactjs code as well

Comment: i was trying to do ajax but i dont know how :(

Answer (score 0):

In your `ajax` call, after your call is successful get the response and call `setState` with new response received.

Now react will `re-render` and your component will be updated with new data from ajax call.

There is no need to call `history.go(0)`.

I have assumed that there is a `TableComponent` which renders the table structure.
`TableComponent` receives `data` as **prop** from `Test` component.

As soon as new data available via ajax call, that data is passed to `TableComponent` and `TableComponent` re-renders itself.

Whole page re-rendering will not occur in this case only changes occur where states were changed.

Check the below code snippet as an example.

```js
class Test extends React.Component {

   constructor(){
     super();
     this.state = {
        data:[]
     };
   }
   
   handleChange = (event, name) => {
    // set state here
   }
  
 handleSubmit( name, address,department) {

 const laman = {
      'Employee_Name': name,
      'Address': address,
      'Department': department
    }
    return fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/PostEmployeeDetail?', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(laman)
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response)
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (result) {
      this.setState({data:result}); // <--------
      // as soon as you will call setState rerender will occur
  
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);

    })
}

  render() {
    return ( 
    <div>
           <form>
<div className="container">
      <div className="modal-body">
          <table> 
          <tbody>
          <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>
          <input type="text"
                ref="Employee_Name"
                onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, "Employee_Name")}
                required
                /> 
          </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>Address</td>
          <td>
           <input type="text"
                 ref="Address"
                onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, "Address")}
                required
                 />
          </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>Department</td>
          <td>
           <input type="text"

                  onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, "Department")}
                  required
          /> 
          </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
          </table>

      </div>
      </div>
      <div className="modal-footer">
        <input type="button" className="btn btn-info" disabled={!isEnabled} 
           onClick = { this.handleSubmit.bind(
                            this, this.state.Employee_Name,
                            this.state.Address,
                            this.state.Department)
                      }
            value =" Add Employee"
            data-dismiss="modal"/>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" >Close</button>
      </div>

        </form>
        
       // your table component or jsx goes here

        // render your table based on state -- data
        <TableComponent data={this.state.data} />
    </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <Test /> ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: im confuse what does the   this.countLines(); do?

Comment: @P.Macs above code snippet will not run as it depends upon your fetch request and also TableComponent has not been added yet. I have just provided you as an example.

Comment: i tried updating my question i hope it helped .. i also try adding your suggested answer but it end up doing the same thing :( i dont know what im doing.. sorry

Comment: are you calling setState after getting new data in your component?

Comment: .then(function (result) {
      this.setState({ jsonReturnedValue: results
                    });
    })

Comment: constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { jsonReturnedValue: [],
                     Department:'',
                     Employee_Name: '',
                     Employee_ID: '',
                     Address: '',
     }