# How to reload the table when clicked using AJAX in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net, fetch-api

I was wondering how will I reload only the table, not the whole page on reacts. I've tried using `history.go(0);` however, it reloads the whole page please check how can I reload it, if I was going to use `forceUpdate`, based on research you should avoid using it. I'm trying do an AJAX but I don't know what to put where to put it; it is way different than PHP.

My code for the `onclick`:

```
 handleSubmit( name, address,department){

 const laman = {
      'Employee_Name': name,
      'Address': address,
      'Department': department
    }
    return fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/PostEmployeeDetail?', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(laman)
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response)
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (result) {
      history.go(0);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);

    })
}
```

this is the code for the onclick button  plus the table itself

```
render() {
     const isEnabled = this.canBeSubmitted();
    let {jsonReturnedValue} = this.state;
  return(
    <div>
        <div className="container">   
          <h1> Listof Employees </h1>
            <button className ='btn btn-warning right ' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddEmployee"> Add an Employee</button>
             <table className= "table table-bordered" id="result"> 
                <tbody>
                 <tr>
                      <th>ID</th>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Address</th>
                      <th>Update</th>
                      <th>Delete</th>
                 </tr>
                    {jsonReturnedValue.map((d,i) => this.renderItem(d,i))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>

      {/*Updating*/}

    <div className="modal fade" id="UpdateEmployee" role="dialog">
           <div className="modal-dialog">
             <div className="modal-content">
                <div className="modal-header">
                   <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  <h4 className="modal-title">ADD  Employee</h4>
            </div>
<form>

        <div className="container">
          <div className="modal-body">
              <table> 
              <tbody>
              <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>
              <input type="text"
                    ref="Employee_Name"
                    onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, "Employee_Name")}
                    required
                    /> 
              </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td>Address</td>
              <td>
               <input type="text"
                     ref="Address"
                    onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, "Address")}
                    required
                     />
              </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td>Department</td>
              <td>
               <input type="text"
                      
                      onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, "Department")}
                      required
              /> 
              </td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
              </table>

          </div>
          </div>
          <div className="modal-footer">
            <input type="button" className="btn btn-info"disabled={!isEnabled} 
                    onClick = { this.handleSubmit.bind(
                                this, this.state.Employee_Name,
                                this.state.Address,
                                this.state.Department)
                                 }
                               value =" Add Employee"
                               data-dismiss="modal"/>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" >Close</button>
          </div>

            </form>
```

PS: IT IS ALSO IN THE SAME PAGE.. the reason I don't know how will I call it

Comment: I suggest using React JS with Redux. You would not have that kind of problem. OR you can play with states inside your component.

Comment: Can you show how you are rendering the data inside the table ?

Comment: okay, edited it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reloads the table when clicked reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44125123/how-to-reloads-the-table-when-clicked-reactjs)

Comment: This appears to be the first of two duplicates of your previous question, and as I have noted, you have duplicated your questions elsewhere as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are contructing the table based on `state jsonReturnedValue`, you need not do anything extra apart from apending the newly added value to this state since, React will Automatically take care of updating only the change

Change the `handleSubmit` function to

```
handleSubmit( name, address,department){

 const laman = {
      'Employee_Name': name,
      'Address': address,
      'Department': department
    }
    return fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/PostEmployeeDetail?', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(laman)
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response)
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((result)=> {
       var jsonReturnedValue = [...this.state.jsonReturnedValue];
       jsonReturnedValue.push(laman);
       this.setState({jsonReturnedValue})
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);

    })
}
```

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Comment: you helped my soul sir :) Thank you again ^^

Comment: In edits, you will have to find the array item which you want to edit, change its values and set to state

Comment: sir how can i set the row i clicked is the array? sorry for too many question im so new to react

Comment: pass the index of the item on click to the edit function, then `var jsonReturnedValue = [...this.state.jsonReturnedValue]; 
jsonReturnedValue[index].Department = "new value" ... etc;
this.setState({jsonReturnedValue})`

Comment: var jsonReturnedValue = [...this.state.jsonReturnedValue]; 
      
      jsonReturnedValue[data].Department = department,
      jsonReturnedValue[data].Employee_name = name,
      jsonReturnedValue[data].Address = address
      this.setState({jsonReturnedValue})

Comment: i tried that .. because the "new value" is the input ..? but it wasnt working

Comment: Can you ask another question with details of the edit content code